# XMLDocument Selection

Tags: c#, xml

The XML document I have is the following format:

```
<response>
   <forecast>
      <txt_forecast>
         <forecastdays>
            <forecastday>
               <period>0</period>
               <fctext>Sunny</fctext>
            </forecastday>
            <forecastday>
               <period>1</period>
               <fctext>Cloudy></fctext>
            </forecastday>
         </forecastdays>
      </txt_forecast>
   </forecast>
</response>
```

And the code I have at the moment is:

```
public String getcurrentForecast()
{
   XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
   doc.Load("http://api.wunderground.com/api/74e1025b64f874f6/forecast/conditions/q/zmw:00000.1.95784.xml");
   XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/response/forecast/txt_forecast/forecastdays/forecastday");
```

I am new to XML reading, and I have spent 2 days trying to understand examples from various sources. I would like to use the 'XMLDocument' property for my code.

How can I select the "peroid 0" node and get the "fctext" text please?

Comment: I added closing elements so that your XML is well-formed. It makes it easier to copy/paste for testing, just like posting compilable code in your questions does. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("http://api.wunderground.com/api/74e1025b64f874f6/forecast/conditions/q/zmw:00000.1.95784.xml");
    XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/response/forecast/txt_forecast/forecastdays/forecastday[period=0]/fcttext");

    String Forecast = node.InnerText;
```

[Update:] There is a free utility here that helps you quickly figure out correct XPath expressions: http://www.bubasoft.net/product/xpath-builder/

Comment: I tried this and Michael Perrenoud's code. While they both work great, this one is much cleaner I feel. Thank you very much for your help. Beautiful coding there.

Answer (score 2):

Your XPath query should be something like

```
//forecastday/period[text()='0']/../fcttext
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using a different library, `XDocument`, instead:

```
byte[] data;
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
    data = webClient.DownloadData(urlToDocument);

string str = Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
var doc = XDocument.Load(str);
var node = doc.Descendants("period")
                .Where(elem => elem.Value == "0")
                .First().NextNode;
var fcText = ((XElement)node).Value;
```

Comment: Everything looks good except for ".Value". It comes up with the error: System.Xml.Linq.XNode does not contain a definition for 'Value'

Comment: @TheWoo, my apologies. Please have a look at my edit.