# C# XML Search For Node Value

Tags: c#, xml, string, nodes

I have a XML document in the following format:

```
<forecast>
   <forecastday>
      <title>monday</title>
      <fcttext>Sunny.</fcttext>
   </forecastday>
   <forecastday>
      <title>tuesday</title>
      <fcttext>Clear</fcttext>
   </forecastday>
```

The *title* node changes the text depending on what day it is today (it is a forecast for the next x amount of days).

I have created a textbox and have sorted the text to look for the name of the day entered, and passed it into a string.

My question is, how can I use the value of the string (say: "monday") to correspond to the node and get the values from that node.

Comment: Parse the XML, get the correct day, do as you please. Start with parsing (`XDocument.Parse`).

Comment: Your question sure looks similar to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20318424/xmldocument-selection/20318552#20318552

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in to XPath Expressions (http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) to search and parse your XML.

To search for the fcttext of a forecastday having title 'tuesday', you'd use the following XPath Expression:

```
//forecastday[title='tuesday']/fcttext
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using this code.

```
string xml = @"<forecast>
                   <forecastday>
                      <title>monday</title>
                      <fcttext>Sunny.</fcttext>
                   </forecastday>
                   <forecastday>
                      <title>tuesday</title>
                      <fcttext>Clear</fcttext>
                   </forecastday></forecast>";

string day = "tuesday";
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
string value = xDoc.XPathSelectElement(String.Format("//forecastday[title='{0}']/fcttext", day)).Value;
```

Replace the value of `day` property with the value from your combo box.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `string` variable with your XML content.

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(input);

var weather = (string)xDoc.Root
                          .Elements("forecastday")
                          .First(x => (string)x.Element("title") == "monday")
                          .Element("fcttext");
```

btw. Your sample XML misses `</forecast>` closing tag.